# SUM a data with some category using if and sumif

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs

im on learning excel here.
so i trying to sum a total unit based on  region west and item is pencil.
i try several things and it doesn't show any value, just blank.
i try

```
=IF(AND(B:B="West";D:D="Pencil");SUMIF(D:D;"Pencil";E:E);"")
```

but it won't work..
please help.. :)

[image: screenshot of the excel]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your formula to:

```
=SUMIFS(E:E;D:D;"Pencil";B:B;"West")
```

Comment: i'd never thought using SUMIFS is more simple.... 
how much category it can if using SUMIFS?

Comment: Hi @TristiantoRaflesia - i am not sure how many criterion pairs can be added. It must be a lot because I have used SUMIFS (and COUNTIFS) with more than 6 columns. It might be somewhere in the documentation from Microsoft.

Comment: You can enter up to 127 range/criteria pairs. SUMIFS function https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b